# iOS - Is it possible that [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] would return only part of the bytes of the content?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Will `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]` either return the full amount of bytes on success, or `nil` if something goes wrong?

Is there a chance, that it would return maybe only half of the bytes of the content... perhaps if their internet connection fails halfway through?

If there is a chance that it would return only partial data, is there some other function I could use that would be more reliable and I would be able to know definitely whether they got the full amount of data or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about the implementation of -dataWithContentsOfURL: but using a sychronous method like this is not really recommended anyway.

Something based on NSURLConnection is your best bet, but you need to be aware of a few things. Most people don't realize that if the server disconnects while an NSURLConnection is receiving data, it will not cause the download to fail with an error. The `-connectionDidFinishLoading:` delegate method will be called as normal. Many people get this wrong.

If you want to be sure you have all the data, you need to handle the `-connection:didReceiveResponse:` delegate method and save the value of `[response expectedContentLength]`. Then in `-connectionDidFinishLoading:` you can make sure you received the same number of bytes as expected, and generate an error if not.

There are many free libraries out there based on `NSURLConnection` like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). However you need to beware of bad code. I've just checked the source to `AFNetworking` and it appears they also do not check for the case where the server sends back less data than the `Content-Length` header specifies. Also note that the popular [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) is no longer being actively developed and has received some criticism over its implementation.

I'll leave it up to others to suggest other alternative libraries, but `NSURLConnection` is the right direction.

Comment: It's okay to use a synchronous request if its on a background thread right? I already have a background thread setup for this work, in addition to some other stuff, and it's much easier with my code if I could use `[NSUrlConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]`. And with that method I could still get the response object and then call [response expectedContentLength].

Comment: Well technically the sychronous call will create another thread in addition to the one it exists in. The sychronous method is just a light wrapper around NSURLConnection that spins off a background thread and then blocks. There is a WWDC video which talks about this but I can't remember the title right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you 'worry' about such a thing I'd recommend using `NSURLConnection` with it's appropriate delegates.

The async approach (that is `NSURLConnection`) is imho always better.